# How to divide circuit load without subpanel

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, subpanel

I have a project where I need to use two 12 amp circuits and they ran one 30amp breaker with 10awg cable. The load lines are 2 devices that pull 10 to 12 amps.

Can I connect both loads on to 10awg wire which has 30amp capacity with wire nuts or do I need to add subpanel with 15amp breakers for both loads?

Comment: The 30 amp breaker is a double breaker(with two hot wires)?  If so can just replace the 30 amp breaker with a double 15 amp  breaker or a double 20 amp breaker, if you can use a MWBC/shared neutral.  If you need two separate circuits, a sub panel seems easiest.

Comment: Pictures ([edit] to add them using the sun and mountains icon) would be helpful, here.

Comment: Are these devices cord-and-plug connected or hardwired?  Do they take 120 or 240V?